# Why my second def inside the first def doesn't function?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to make a program that can check whether the entered number is a prime number in Jupyter Notebook. This is the code:

```
def input_number():
     number = input()
     if number.isnumeric():
         the_number = int(number)
         def check_prime():
             divisor = 1
             divisor += 1
             if the_number > 1:
                 if divisor in range(2, the_number):
                     if the_number % divisor != 0:
                         print(the_number, "is a prime number")
                     else:
                         print(the_number,"not a prime number")
                         print(the_number, "divide", number//divisor, "is", divisor)
             else:
                 print(the_number, "not a prime number")
     else:
```

But when I enter a number the process will not continue to `def check_prime` and it just freezes. If I enter anything other than a number then I get

```
**UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'check_prime' where it is not associated with a value**
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined that function under `input_number()`
You can only use `check_prime()` under that function.

define the `check_prime()` outside of `input_number()`.

```
def input_number(): #input number func
    number = input() #take the number
    return int(number) if number.isnumeric() else print('Input only INT.') #return the number swapped to int if its numeric.

def check_prime(the_number): #prime function - num is a parameter to use in function
    # you  defined divisor than added 1 , but its same with defining it as 2.
    divisor = 2  # you also dont need to define divisor
    if the_number > 1:
        if divisor in range(2, the_number):
            if the_number % divisor != 0:
                print(the_number, "is a prime number")
            else:
                print(the_number, "not a prime number")
                print(the_number, "divide", the_number // divisor, "is", divisor)
    else:
        print(the_number,'not a prime number.')
```

while calling, use

```
check_prime(input_number)
```